# MSBuild - can I compile all solutions in child directories?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way in MSBuild to compile all solutions in folders, and sub-folders, and sub... under a specified parent?

We have a bunch of sample programs we ship with our library. I want to add to the build process that we know they all compile.

Comment: Iterate the solution files and pass them one by one to MSBuild (either API or command line).

Comment: Is this what you wanted? Or?

Answer (score 3):

You can create own `targets` for `restore` and `build` operations. For example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="EntryRestore" DefaultTargets="EntryMSBuild">

  <ItemGroup>
    <SolutionFile Include="./**/*.sln"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="EntryRestore">

    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="    Restore    " Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionFile.Identity)" Targets="restore"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="EntryMSBuild">

    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="     Build     " Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="-----Entry-----" Importance="high" />

    <MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionFile.Identity)" Targets="build"  />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

---

Item `SolutionFile` will contains paths for all `.sln` files that located in current directory and its subdirectories. You also may define path in `CLI` and perform searching relative it.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SolutionFile Include="$(MyDir)/**/*.sln"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

---

`MSBuild` task launches `MSBuild` for performing specified targets. In our cas it are `restore` and `build`. It task used '`batching`' that allow iterate over items by metadata.

---

```
&"D:\Visual Studio\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" .\Make.targets
```

---

[MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets) | [Item element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild) | [Item metadata in task batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-metadata-in-task-batching) | [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task)

Comment: Plase name the restore target `Restore` and use the `/restore` command line switch instead of `InitialTargets` to initiate the restore. it is the only way to ensure proper cache clearing during restore + build operations.

Comment: @MartinUllrich, can you explain more detailed?